# Best practise for store/edit setting for custom time job?

Tags: 2007, custom, timer-jobs

What's the best practise for store/edit setting for custom time job?

Well, we have OOTB _admin/Timer.aspx and /_admin/JobEdit.aspx pages, but if we have custom timer job with some setting (by the way, SPJobDefinition impl SPPersistedObject and we can store some setting in jon instance) we need to provide some UI for user/administrator to change timer job setting.
It isn't hard - to develop custom aspx page for this task, but, for example, we have 10-20 different job and we don't like "custon page-per-job development".

What is the best way for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN recommends using the guidance library configuration manager, property bag, which can be scoped to the farm.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413917.aspx

Comment: Right, but if we want to change some job setting we need to write custom aspx page for that task. "Page per job" in bad case.

May be where is more commom way to edit/change job props?

/_admin/JobEdit.aspx is good page for that, but this page can't be extended.
For example, if we could add some attributes to job ptoperties and they would show at /_admin/JobEdit.aspx page but no way, we can't.

Comment: you could easily write a single aspx page that could manage the properties in teh configuration manager, filtering however you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the "[Config Store](http://spconfigstore.codeplex.com/)", which is a codeplex project. It is basically a SharePoint list that allows you to add your key/values in and then programatically read them at run time. Like 'appsettings' without the web.config modifications. Very useful.

Comment: I don't think it is good solution for timer job which for example run across the all farm. It is not so good to link some specific jobs to web-scoped-settings ot even spsite-scoped-settings.